# VBA code to enable three Cells, each in its own worksheet, equal to each other always

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have three cells in three worksheets: Cell A1 in Sheet1, Cell A2 in Sheet2 and Cell A3 in Sheet 3.
I would like to have values in the three cells always equal to each other. This means that an update in any of the cells affects the other cells.
I tried writing a macro that updates values in cells A2 and A3 whenever cell A1 is changed. This seemed to work well. When I tried doing the same for cell A2, the macros generated a run time error. It appears the two macros created an infinite loop; User changes value in Cell A1, Macro 1 updates Cell A2, Macro 2 detects a change in Cell A2 and updates Cell A1, Macro 1 detects the change in Cell A1 and the loop continues ...
Can anyone provide VBA Code to achieve this behavior (A1=A2=A3 always) and the logic therein. I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 release.

Comment: Looks like you're suffering an event loop (no idea if that's the official name for it)..... you change a value which causes the `Change` event to fire, the change event changes the value in a cell which causes the `Change` event to fire again.  You can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to disable the event before updating the cell.  Remember to re-enable it again afterwards.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that the event procedure will not keep calling itself and getting
stuck in an infinite loop, use this VBA command before setting the other
cells to disable event procedures from firing:

```
Application.EnableEvents=False
```

To enable them back again :

```
Application.EnableEvents=True
```

Surround the problematic code with these two commands to avoid the loop.

Reference :
[Application.EnableEvents property (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents).